# Symfony 2: How do deal big tasks user friendly

Tags: php, symfony

I implemented a newsletter function.

The user can select a list form his customers that he want send a newsletter to, the list of customers can possible be a few thousand entries large.

After the user finished to create the list I'd will a database with all information I need from the list. Now I want to make this process as user friendly as possible.

I thought about the following:

1. User finishes his list and clicks on "save"
2. I take the information and return an view like "Action is running. Please wait, this action can take a few minutes"
3. I'm writing the information from the list into my database
4. I redirect the user from the "please wait" view to another view where he can work from again.

My problem is that I can't figure out how I could implement this in symfony2, would there be a possibility with events or should I save the list in the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options. The most common two are:

- AJAX call with javascript
- Using a queue (like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ)

I prefer the queue because it's more manageable. In Symfony2 there are a few packages available to implement a queue system:

- RabbitMQ Bundle: https://packagist.org/packages/oldsound/rabbitmq-bundle
- ZeroMQ library: https://github.com/reactphp/zmq

You can search for alternatives on https://packagist.org

I would implement the following flow:

1. Render a form
2. Post form
3. Handle form: save information to DB
4. Handle form: send corresponding to a queue
5. Inform the user with a flashbag

In the backend:

1. Start a consumer (CLI)
2. Get information from the queue
3. Send your newsletter
4. Update the database with the new status and log

At the frontend: Inform the user if the database is updated and the status is changed